# Jenkins Pipeline still executes following stages even though current stage failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm implementing a `try catch` block on most of my stages inside my `jenkins pipeline` to skip all the following stages when the current stage fails however, one of my stages is returning an error but still continues to execute the next stages.

I've tried using `sh 'exit 1', currentStage.result = 'FAILED'`, if else clause to check the stage result but to no avail.

```js
pipeline {
 agent none
 stages {
  stage ('one') {
   steps {
    echo 'Next stage should be skipped if this stage fails'
    script {
     try {
      sh '''#!/bin/bash -l
      source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
      nvm use node
      node somefile.js'''
     }
     catch (e) {
      currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE';
      throw e
     }
    }
   }
   }
  stage ('two') {
   steps {
    echo 'This stage should be skipped if prior stage throws an erorr'
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I expect stage two to be skipped as my `somefile.js` is throwing an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `when-clause` that Jenkins provides ([Source](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)).

```
    stage ('two') {
        // Skip this stage if pipeline has already failed
        when { not { equals expected: 'FAILURE', actual: currentBuild.result } }
        steps {
            echo 'This stage should be skipped if prior stage throws an erorr'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Although I was able to fix it by not using the not condition and proceeded with `when { equals expected: 'SUCCESS', actual: currentBuild.result }`

Comment: Yes, your `when{}` does work too. Jenkins can also have the state `UNSTABLE` (the yellow one) so consider this if you improve your pipeline in the future because your stage wouldnt be executed in this case.

Comment: Will take note of that. Thank you. However, I have an additional question. I tried adding another condition on my when clause as: `when { allOf { branch 'sandbox'
equals expected: 'SUCCESS', actual: currentBuild.result } }` but it's still running the stage two even if stage one failed.

Comment: You code seems to be correct. Did you split the 2 condigitions into 2 different lines? I think this will be necessary.

Comment: Maybe create another question. I think this goes beyond the scope of this one. I will give it a look.